# Python: Unicode and "\xe2\x80\x99" driving me batty

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

So I have a .txt file from Google Docs containing some lines from David Foster Wallace's "Oblivion". Using:

```
with open("oblivion.txt", "r", 0) as bookFile:
    wordList = []
    for line in bookFile:
        wordList.append(line)
```

and returning & printing the wordList I get:

```
"surgery on the crow\xe2\x80\x99s feet around her eyes."
```

(and it truncates a lot of the text). However, if instead of appending the wordList I simply

```
for line in bookFile:
    print line
```

everything turns out fine! The same goes for .read()'ing the file - the resulting str doesn't have the crazy byte representation, but then I can't manipulate it the way I want to.

Where do I .encode() or .decode() or what? <s>Using Python 2 because 3 was giving me some I/O buffer error.</s> Thanks.

Comment: I'd solve the I/O error instead.

Comment: Your output is correct. When you print a list strings inside it will be shown escape. You see the hexadezimal representation `\xe2\x80\x99` of the Unicode character `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`. Using is there is typographically incorrect but a common mistake.

Comment: In python 3, try removing the 0-arg from: with open("oblivion.txt", "r", 0) as bookFile:

Comment: It is likely only a console output issue and no issue in the program itself. It was the case with me when I hit this issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `open` with `encoding` as `utf-8`:

```
with open("oblivion.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as bookFile:
    wordList = bookFile.readlines()
```

Comment: This worked in Python 3. Didn't realize I could encode from the get-go. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck with Python 2 and want to use Rahul's answer

```
import io
with io.open("oblivion.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as bookFile:
    wordList = bookFile.readlines()
```

Comment: When you are trying to open a file with 'rb' encoding is not accepted as a parameter. 
This answer correctly solved my problem even in the current release of python (3.9)

Comment: @techcheese If you open with 'rb' you explicitly open in *read-binary* mode, i.e. without encoding. Having an encoding doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: yes, when I opened in read-binary it still didn't read the punctuation marks correctly. The solution you provided worked  though.